principal component analysis with missing data
What would be the best approach to deal with missing data in a dataset when we want to run a PCA and then use the participant component scores extracted from the PCA as predictors in a mediation model? There seems to be a lot of variability in approaches, so I was wondering what is the recommended approach.
I have come across the following approaches:
a) First run the multiple imputation, then run the PCA on all the imputed datasets, extract component scores per participant and then average them before including in the mediation model or
b) Run a PCA on the incomplete data, extract the principal components, and then run a multiple imputation on the incomplete dataset with the principal component scores and then fit the mediation model on all the imputed datasets?
I may have not come across an even better approach, so please let me know if I am missing something that work much better. Thank you!
As suggested by Ben Bolker, I had looked at the missMDA package but I am kind confused by using "estim_ncpPCA" to determine the number of components to impute. Looking at the scree plot for the incomplete data there should be 2 components, but "estim_ncpPCA" only identified one.

Should I use 1 as suggested and still retrieve the component scores for 2 components as in the code below?
library(missMDA)

nb <- estim_ncpPCA(dat, ncp.min = 0, ncp.max = 8, nbsim = 100, pNA = 0.05) # estimate the number of components from incomplete data
nb$ncp #1 component
plot(0:7, nb$criterion, xlab = "nb dim", ylab = "MSEP")
res.comp <- imputePCA(dat, ncp = nb$ncp) # iterativePCA algorithm
res.comp$completeObs[1:3,] # the imputed data set
imp <- cbind.data.frame(res.comp$completeObs, dat)

pca2 <- psych::principal(dat, nfactors = 2, rotate = "oblimin")  
pca2
psych::print.psych(pca2, cut = 0.3)


http://juliejosse.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/DataAnalysisMissingR.html#pca_with_missing_values ?

I actually came across this, but this section "nb <- estim_ncpPCA(don,method.cv = "Kfold", verbose = FALSE)" produces only 1 component which is not in line with the scree plot for the PCA on the incomplete data. Is this okay? I am a bit confused by it.
